# Changing CSS property with JS mousemove performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, animation

I have a jQuery function changing the `background-position` property of three elements on `mousemove` and this seems to be causing some performance issues.

It should be noted that the background images of these elements are SVGs.

Example code:

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {

        $banner.find('.pattern').each(function(key) {

            var modifier = 20 * (key + 1);

            $(this).css({
                'background-position': (event.pageX / modifier)+'px '+(event.pageY / modifier)+'px'
            });

        });

    });
});
```

See my working code here: https://codepen.io/thelevicole/project/full/DarVMY/

I am making use of `window.requestAnimationFrame()` and I also have `will-change: background-position;` css attribute on each element.

As you can probably tell, this effect is lagging. It seems to get worse on bigger window sizes.

I'm pretty sure the issue is caused by using SVGs for the background images instead of PNGs. The reason I am using SVGs is because of high pixel density screens.

If anyone can give some insight on how I can improve the FPS without having to use PNGs that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using your svg's as inline elements instead of background-image and then moving them using transforms?

Comment: Can't you invoke the *find* method outside the event function? I think you can calculate it only once in the outer scope and reuse the reference:
`$patterns = $banner.find('.pattern');
$(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
     $patterns.each(function(key) ...`

Comment: You can also get rid of JQuery and use the appropriate javascript DOM methods, it will give you further performance

Comment: [Four things a browser can animate cheaply: `translate`, `scale`, `rotate`, and `opacity`.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) Can you rewrite your JS to use `transform: translate()` instead of repositioning backgrounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success. My solution has been a combination of suggestions.

I am now changing the transform property of each element but I ran into another issue while doing this. I have a transform keyframe animation on those same elements and the JS applied styles were being ignored.

To fix this I nested the the keyframe animation elements and used JS to transform the parent.

I have applied the advice from @CristianTraìna to move `window.requestAnimationFrame()` outside of my `mousemove`

You can see the update at my original link: https://codepen.io/thelevicole/project/full/DarVMY/

Sadly CodePen doesn't allow for versioning on projects.

---

Final working code

```js
(function($) {
 'use strict';
 
 var $banner = $('section.interactive');
 if ($banner.length) {
  var $patterns = $banner.find('.pattern');
  
  var x = 0,
   y = 0;
  
  // Bind animation to cursor
  $(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
   x = event.pageX;
   y = event.pageY;
  });
  
  /**
   * Tell the browser that we wish to perform an animation
   * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame
   */
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function animation() {

   // Loop each pattern layer
   $patterns.each(function(key) {

    // Modify the x,y coords per element to give "depth"
    var modifier = 20 * (key + 1);

    // Move background position
    $(this).css({
     'transform': 'translate('+(x / modifier)+'px, '+(y / modifier)+'px)'
    });

   });
   
   window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);

  });
  
  
 }
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
section.interactive {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #6ac8ea 0%, #5de2c1 100%);
}

section.interactive .layers {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
}

section.interactive .layers .pattern {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  background-position: top left;
  will-change: background-position;
  background-size: 1000px 1000px;
}

section.interactive .layers .pattern .inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

section.interactive .layers .pattern.pattern-1 .inner {
  background-image: url("http://www.inrialpes.fr/sed/people/boissieux/VEAD/out_Stars.svg");
  filter: blur(2px);
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: Floating 10s infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  background-size: 800px 800px;
}

section.interactive .layers .pattern.pattern-2 .inner {
  background-image: url("http://www.inrialpes.fr/sed/people/boissieux/VEAD/out_Stars.svg");
  filter: blur(1px);
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: Floating 10s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  background-size: 900px 900px;
}

section.interactive .layers .pattern.pattern-3 .inner {
  background-image: url("http://www.inrialpes.fr/sed/people/boissieux/VEAD/out_Stars.svg");
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: Floating 10s infinite;
  background-size: 1000px 1000px;
}

@keyframes Floating {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Animation performance</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.processed.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="interactive">
  <div class="layers">
   <div class="pattern pattern-3">
    <div class="inner"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="pattern pattern-2">
    <div class="inner"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="pattern pattern-1">
    <div class="inner"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, great that you found the answer! Could you include the code of your answer so future use don't rely on codepen to get it?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the *on* method you are creating an asynchronous function that will listen to an event, when this event is fired you create another asynchronous function that will listen to an event.

Then, what you're doing is listening to an event (*mousemove*) and set another event (*requestAnimationFrame*) when the first is fired, but what if mousemove is fired twice in a short time and requestAnimationFrame still didn't execute its callback the first time?

A cleaner way to solve the problem is this:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
$patterns = $banner.find('.pattern');
$(window).on('mousemove', function(event) {
  x = event.pageX;
  y = event.pageY;
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(function moveBackground() {
  $patterns.each(function(key) {
    var modifier = 20 * (key + 1);
    $(this).css({
      'background-position': (x / modifier)+'px '+(y / modifier)+'px'
    });
  });
  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
});
```

You can see my working project (without JQuery) [clicking here](https://codepen.io/crisz/pen/MEmPzo)